# Express can't server static file from another directory

Tags: express

I have a js file that is in different directory from the express server. To serve this file, I have below line of code that is not working:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/.."+"/first-app"+"/Coursera"+"/index_bundle.js")));
```

The directory structure is this:

```
-> Parent
 ->Project
   ->express server
 ->first-app
   ->Coursera
     ->index_bundle.js
```

But the browser cannot fetch the js file that is included in the html file served from express.
I am serving the js file like this:

```
<script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
```

I have tried atleast 5-6 different paths but it is not working. Can someone help me to spot the error?

Comment: Which directory in your diagram is `__dirname` in your first line of code?

Comment: Also, you will generally want to use a link in your HTML with a leading `/` so you control what the browser requests independently of the path of the URL of the page that contains it: `<script src="/index_bundle.js"></script>`.

Comment: __dirname is the path of express server. It is ``/home/Documents/express_server``

Comment: `/home/Documents/express_server` does not match your diagram at all.  You show it in `Parent/Project/express_server`.  And, you show that `first-app` is in `Parent/first-app`.  So, what you have in your question doesn't match your comment above.

Comment: Actually express_server is not a directory. It is server.js file. That is why I have to go only one level up

Comment: I asked you what `__dirname` was.  That's a directory.  Not a file.  I think I'm going to take a break on this one because you're giving us misleading information which makes it impossible to help.  You aren't giving us the actual facts here.  This is an easy question to resolve if we have ALL the correct facts about where everything is, but impossible to guess if we don't.

Comment: __dirname is ``home/Documents/Parent``. I have my file at ``home/Documents/Parent/first-app/Coursera/``. Now this should clear all doubts about __dirname.

Comment: I don't think there is anything confusing in the __dirname. I simply want to know how to include any static file that is one directory above where server is running

Comment: Hey, it's working. Let me tell you what the problem was. The problem was that I was using the ``app.use`` before ``app.get('/')``. Then I moved ``app.use()`` to after ``app.get('/')`` and it started working.

Comment: What version is working?

Comment: The __dirname that I have given was just fine. See above comments.

Comment: Version of what?? didn't get that

Comment: Never mind.  I'm apparently of no help here and not enjoying this.  I will just leave.  FYI, you have two different values for `__dirname` in your comments in case you wonder why we were confused.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Hey, I have used the pathname you have given and that is working. The only thing is that the problem is not the same you were suspecting. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Even if it would have same, it wouldn't have worked because the problem was something else.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I admit initially I gave wrong path but later in one of my comment, I corrected it. You have been of great help. Thanks again